# Mongoose deleting all documents at every one minute and not accepting time from `expires` and `expireAfterSeconds`

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

We are using express and mongoose, we are trying to remove the document every 1000 seconds in the background, but MongoDB removes at an unexpected time. how to solve it?. also would like to know the difference between `expires` and `expireAfterSeconds`.

MongoDB - v3.6.5,
mongoose - 5.4.3,
express - 4.16.4

Sample Model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const forgotPassword = mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: [true, 'Email field is required']},
    expiresAt: { type: Date, expires: '2m', default: Date.now }
}, { timestamps: true, versionKey: false, strict: false });

forgotPassword.index({ expiresAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 1000 });
module.exports = mongoose.model('forgotpassword', forgotPassword);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expires and expireAfterSeconds uses [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/):

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task.

Your documents are expected to be removed between 2 and 3 min.

**UPDATE**:

Check if the collection has correct indexes. Mongoose do not update indexes if the collection already have it.

If expiration time was 0 when you first created the index the documents will be removed within a minute whatever changes you do in your js code until you drop the index, collection, or the whole database.

Use [syncIndexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes) to update indexes on the database side, but be careful to ensure it doesn't happen often on production. It may be quite expensive on large collections.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but documents removing before 2 minutes, sometimes less than 1 minutes. removing process is not stable.

Comment: May I know the correct way of using TTL in my script? Can I use any one of `expires` or `expireAfterSeconds`?

Comment: Yes, We have two expiry indexes with 0, we cleared now and It works. shall we keep  `model.syncIndexes();` in production?

Comment: Yes, but only in the deployment pipeline, not from operational code. You need to sync indexes only once when you deploy new version of the application.